# How is a neural network called that is NOT convolutional

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

how is a neural network called that is NOT a convolutional neural network and not an RNN?

For example, I want to google stuff for "normal" neural networks. But if I type "neural network not convolutional" all results are CNNs.

Answer (score 2):

Non-recurrent networks are called **feedforward neural networks**. You could add **fully connected** to emphasize that it is not convolutional.